# Can the EWRF 3022 module be directly connected to the pc totransmit data from the pc wirelessly?

Tags: nrf24l01+, wireless, rf

In my project I want to connect my pc to an RF transmitter. The receiver will be connected to an arduino on my robot. However most of the RF modules I looked up couldn't be directly connected to my computer- in all of them I needed to use an arduino on the transmitter end too. Then I came across this:

> [EWRF 3022](http://www.swechtrading.se/zencart/images/datablad/ewrf3022ut.pdf)

Can this be directly connected to my computer? If so, how is it done?

Comment: How many modules are you going to ask the same question for? You can find out for yourself: Look to see if the module has a PC interface - that is (generally) a USB or RS-232 interface. If it has then yes you can. If it hasn't then no you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a USB to TTL UART adapter, such as an FT232 dongle, then yes you can communicate to it from a PC.

It will not directly connect to a PC though without you getting that extra hardware.

Comment: Thanks. Also, what are some other similar, more popular, modules having a PC interface? I mean, is there one which is more commonly used for this purpose?

Comment: The only common wireless systems that have a direct PC are WiFi and Bluetooth. Anything else people design a dongle.

Comment: What about xbees? They have a USB explorer board, by which they can be directly connected to a pc.  The only problem with them is the cost.

Comment: That is really no different to using an nRF24L01 with an Arduino, or whatever that is you linked to above with a TTL to UART adapter. I don't see what you have against using extra hardware, especially when you yourself then suggest using extra hardware.

Comment: In another answer, you said that using a TTL to UART adapter will require writing more software, right? If I remember what I read correctly, the xbees involve significantly less coding right? How so?

Comment: I don't know, I have never used an XBee. I think there is some kind of configuration program that sets them up. However, you will still need to write some software to do the communicating.

Comment: Ok. I see. Could you also elaborate on what software I have to write to make it work?

Comment: No, I can't. What software you need to write depends on what you are doing and what you are doing it with.